# How can I make (almost) all fields in all forms disabled for unauthorized users?

Tags: django

I have several complex class-based views for modelforms with inline formsets, new forms being displayed fetched by AJAX and other such stuff. I want to allow unauthorized users to view everything, but only edit one field in a specific form. What I'm currently thinking of is to disable fields on the frontend via JS, then clean out disallowed fields during form cleaning for the one editable form and disallow POSTing everything else, but this seems somewhat clunky. Are there any other viable approaches for doing this without involvement of Javascript?

Comment: You should be able to find out if a user is authorized or unauthorized in the request, and then you can edit your form fields to be readonly.

Comment: @wdfc You misunderstood my question. I don't want to edit all forms manually - ideally I want to make all fields an unauthorized user sees readonly at a low level. Imagine if I edited the definition of `django.forms.fields.Field` to read `self.disabled = True`.

Comment: Please post code.

Comment: Er, what code? I currently have nothing related to this question, only a lot of views inheriting from the generics. I'm specifically looking for a solution that doesn't involve editing every view, so I don't see how posting them can help with anything.

Comment: Im asking to post code because I don't understand what you are asking lol. Just write your own form class inheriting from forms with whatever disabled fields you want, if you don't want to edit every single view create a mixin with your logic and have all your views that need it use that mixin

Answer (score 0):

Without javascript you will have to disable each input with the 'disabled' attribute, setting it within your form via php echos.

```
<inputtype="text" name="lname" <? if(!$enabled) echo 'disabled' ?>>
```

Which could end up being even more clunky. Because on the front end with javascript you could use jquery to disable al inputs with one line of code:

```
$('input').prop('disabled', true);
```

Then enable just the specific input(s) after that. Which is clean way to go.

```
$('#elid).prop('disabled', false);
```

At this point then, you just have to authenticate the user and use this method if the user is not alllowed to edit fields.

---

Nevermind. I did not notice the Django tag.
 My answer is irrelevant.

Comment: Note the "django" tag. PHP is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: Crap. Im new to answering questions on here. Made my way here through flipboard and didnt notice the tag. Face palm.